# I am trying to print out the highest bidder Part 2 *Beginner*

Tags: python, arrays, loops, dictionary

I am trying to print out the highest bidder after trying to code this from scratch. I have stared at this for an hour and cannot figure out why it all works but it always declares the most recent bidder as the winner, not the highest. A fresh pair of eyes would be appreciated!

```
#print(logo)
#Then we set variables to store the inputs
print("Welcome to the secret auction program.\n")

#We then create a dictionary to store the functions output
bidders = []

#Function to add bids to dictionary
def create_bidder(name, bid):
    bidders.append({
        "name": name,
        "bid" : bid
    })

start_name = input("What is your name?\n")
start_bid = input("What's your bid?\n")
create_bidder(start_name,start_bid)
keep_going = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'\n")

while keep_going == "yes":
    clear()
    name = input("What is your name?\n")
    bid = input("What's your bid?\n")
    keep_going = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'\n")
    create_bidder(name, bid)
    
for i in range(0, len(bidders)):
        maxBid = -1
        maxBidName = "";

        bid = int(bidders[i]["bid"])
        name = bidders[i]["name"]

        if bid > maxBid:
                maxBid = bid
                maxBidName = name

if keep_going == 'no':
    for i in range(0, len(bidders)):
        maxBid = -1
        maxBidName = "";

        bid = int(bidders[i]["bid"])
        name = bidders[i]["name"]

        if bid > maxBid:
                maxBid = bid
                maxBidName = name
    print(f"Congratulations {maxBidName}! Your bid of ${maxBid} wins!")

    
if keep_going == 'print':
    print(bidders)
```

Comment: You’re resetting `maxBid = -1` **every single iteration in the loop!** Set it *once* before the loop.

Comment: You set max_bid to -1 on every loop iteration so any positive value will be accepted as new max bid each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `maxBid` out of the `for` loop, in your `keep_gooing == 'no'` case. It would look like this:

```
maxBid = 0
maxBidName = ""

for bidder in bidders:
    bid = int(bidder["bid"])
    name = bidder["name"]

    if bid > maxBid:
            maxBid = bid
            maxBidName = name
print(f"Congratulations {maxBidName}! Your bid of ${maxBid} wins!")
```

If the `maxBid` is inside the for loop, it will be setted to `-1` every time the loop runs!